# Как забрать данные из ссылки?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть сайт с такой ссылкой.
https://site.ru?num=121241
Как забрать это число 121241 в переменную php?
Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду как получить их в файле?  Тогда массив  `$_GET['num']`

Answer (score 1):

Данное значение уже находится в get-переменной. Пример:

```
<php?
echo $_GET['num']; // выведет 121241
```

Если же вы хотите получить это значение из внешнего url, тогда:

```
// адрес сайта 
$url = 'https://site.ru?num=121241';

// получаем query параметр из строки
$qu = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// разбиваем строку на get-параметры
parse_str($qu, $output);

// выводим значение num
echo $output['num'];
```

Comment: Я имею ввиду будет ссылка такая: http://site.ru?num=1234&id=5211 Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Так не важно, какая будет ссылка. Все, что идет после символа ? относится к get-параметрам. Т.е. в ссылке site.ru?num=1234&id=5211 содержится два параметра: num и id. В скрипте $_GET['num'] выведет 1234, а $_GET['id'] = 5211

Answer (score 0):

Если знак `=` встречается только один раз, то можно так:

```
$str = 'https://site.ru?num=121241';
$numb = ltrim(strstr($str, '='), '=');

echo $numb; // 121241
```

Иначе - с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = 'https://site.ru?num=121241&num2=232345';

preg_match_all('~=(\d+)~', $str, $numbers);

var_dump($numbers[1]);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '121241' (length=6)
  1 => string '232345' (length=6)
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду если знак = встречается только один раз?

Comment: Подскажите как занести ссылку в переменную?

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт ваш то $_GET['num'], если просто распарить юрл то parse_url($url_string) подойдёт http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://site.ru?num=121241';
$parse = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parse['query'], $query);
var_dump($query['num']);
```